# css file changes influence the whole application instead of specific model

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using css in my react application in that way :

```
import styles from "./register.module.css";

<div className={styles.banana}>
Hello
</div>
```

Today I made some changes to one of my css modules and realised that it changes the whole application. For example, if I add margin-top to `<h1>` in one of my css files, it will change all the `<h1>` in the entire application, even though other models aren't even importing this css file.

What may be the cause to this issue?

Comment: What module bundler are you using? `webpack` or what's inside `create-react-app`?

Comment: I believe that I am using the default one that comes with create-react-app. I may have webpack installed but I haven't changed the module bundler as far as I know

Comment: What's the `react-scripts` version? [version 2](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) supports it apparently. Also I know that might sound stupid but try to rename file to first letter uppercase.`Register.module.css`

Comment: Your suggestion of the capital letters did not work. And I have the newest react version